# adding a type before a variable in a function parameter list in php

Tags: php

Just curious, using LAMP.

In the following

> public function zhou(array $shenme){
>
> }

What is the purpose of "array" there?

Cheers

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [Type Hinting (EN)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) or [Tipos Sugeridos (ES)](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.typehinting.php) as explained in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

In php you can force a function parameter to be of a certain class. In this case it must be an array. Keep in mind that you can only do this for class names and array not string or boolean or integer.